# argument got ignored in CMD in Dockerfile

Tags: r, docker, plumber

I have a dockerfile as below

but when i run it and check logs, it says, "ARGUMENT 'plumber_2.R' **ignored**". I have tried with diffrent ports as well.

I have tried with different ports but failed

```
FROM r-base:3.5.1

# Install Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev/unstable \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev

## RUN R -e 'install.packages(c("devtools"))'
## RUN R -e 'devtools::install_github("trestletech/plumber")'
#

RUN install2.r plumber
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('MLmetrics','datasets','tsDyn','ggplot2','zoo','forecast'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
WORKDIR /usr/plumberR

COPY . /usr/plumberR
RUN sudo apt-get install curl

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["R", "-e", "pr <- plumber::plumb(commandArgs()[4]); pr$run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)"]
CMD ["plumber_2.R"]


expected is the output but I am getting "ARGUMENT ["plumbr_2.R"] __ignored__
```

Comment: Why do you run `pr <- plumber::plumb(commandArgs()[4]); pr$run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)` in entrypoint and `plumber_2.R` in CMD. I wonder the former could be in the `plumber_2.R`

Comment: didn't get you, can you write(in format of code) what you were saying?

Comment: ENTRYPOINT ["R", "-e", "pr <- plumber::plumb(commandArgs()[4]); pr$run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, swagger=TRUE)", "plumber_2.R"]

Answer (score 0):

Your third `ENTRYPOINT` argument breaks the sequence. It should be taken in additional quotes, but unfortunately you use single quotes internally for host specification.

### Option 1

If you dont plan to override `CMD` in your future calls to `docker run`, you can avoid JSON schema in `ENTRYPOINT/CMD` and use something like:

```
ENTRYPOINT R -e pr <- plumber::plumb(commandArgs()[4]); pr$run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000) plumber_2
```

### Option 2

Put 3rd argument in single quotes and somehow avoid useing them for hot specification:

```
"'pr <- plumber::plumb(commandArgs()[4]); pr$run(port=8000)'"
```